# Find Matches in Sublist and Category

Tags: excel, office-2010

I have a list of 722 names on sheet 1. On sheet 2 I have 31 names of full-time people and 24 of part-time people.

How can I find all of the full-time people and all of the part-time people in Excel without using VBA?

I've looked at VLOOKUP, INDEX and Advanced Filter. Advanced Filter seems the most promising but I can't seem to get around the logic of find both subsets.

The list on sheet 1 doesn't have the category (full-time and part-time) just the names. The category is on sheet 2 only.

**EDIT**

After looking at the issue a little more, the category is not really important. I just need to find a subset of names from the original set.

Comment: How do you want to find? Do you want them highlighted or write in the row number, etc.?

Comment: I'd like to just filter the list on sheet 1 (the 722 names) with the range I select from sheet two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the categories are text, first sheet has names in Sheet1!A2:A723 and second sheet has data in Sheet2!A2:B56, please try:

in Sheet1, in B2: `=IFERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0),"")`
in Sheet1, in C2: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")`

each copied down to row 723. Filter to exclude (Blanks), if required.

The numeric results should indicate the related row number in Sheet2 and the text results the relevant type of employment.